# About spring boot startup vm options relative path problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwX8Z.png)

[enter image description here][2]
I want to specify vm options to reference a file from resource in the jar package when the spring boot service is started. How should I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwX8Z.png)

Comment: Expand Modify options tab and see you would be able to view VM arguments as well as Program arguments!

Comment: [Why should I no upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - please read and fix.

Comment: The java jar URL support  `!` in the URL to reference the folder/file in jar (see here for details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) though I am not sure if javaagent support this schema too.